# Read csv files from website rar folder directly in Python

Tags: python, csv, http, rar

I would like to read csv files directly from a website rar folder.

I have a link to a rar folder:

```
http://.../folder.rar
```

in which there're several csv files.

How can I extract each single file directly in Python?

I found the [remoteunrar](https://pypi.org/project/remoteunrar/) package, and tried the following (as explained in the documentation):

```
import remoteunrar

with remoteunrar('http://.../folder.rar') as rar:
    rar.extract('file.csv')
```

but it returns an error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

(You can try with [ecobee_thermostat](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00442/Ecobee_Thermostat/) as an example; if gives the same error)

How can I read these files directly in Python?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `zipfile` module along with `requests`
this works form me

```
import requests, zipfile, io
r = requests.get('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00442/Ecobee_Thermostat/mirai_attacks.rar?')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall("/path/location")
```

Comment: Thank you @Anti_cse51 for your answer. Although it doesn't work with ```zipfile``` because of a file format error (it is a rar not a zip). Instead I tried with ```rarfile``` and it worked (```z = rarfile. RarFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))```). However, this code downloads the files locally. And I would like to read them (store them) directly in python as dataframes. Is it possible?

Comment: did you try `df = pd.read_csv('filename.rar')`?

Comment: what is a ```rar``` is the folder containing multiple ```csv``` files, not the file itself. I would like something like what you say, but for the files inside the ```rar```. I've tried directly this: ```df = pd.read_csv(z.extract("file.csv"))``` , but of course it's downloading the file anyway. I could go with that, but I wonder if there's any other option that avoids the download.

Comment: tried this ? https://github.com/fcvarela/pyremotezip
pure python module to extract files from remote zip archives without downloading the whole zip archive. Probably exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like below:

1. created folder for extract files
2. extracted all to `FolderForExtract` (empty folder)

```
from pyunpack import Archive
from zipfile import ZipFile
import rarfile

def extract_rar(file):
    rar = rarfile.RarFile(file)
    Archive(file).extractall('FolderForExtract')

def extract_zip(file):
    zip = ZipFile(file)
    zip.extractall('FolderForExtract')
```

3. got needed files
4. deleted all files with rar

I couldn't find other ways

Also I tried read rar by link, but couldn't extract. Maybe this code can help find another way to unpack rar using link:

```
from io import BytesIO
from pyunpack import Archive
import urllib.request
import rarfile
import patoolib


resp = urllib.request.urlopen("url")
r = rarfile.RarFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))
print(r.namelist())

# patoolib.extract_archive(resp.read(), '.') 
# Archive(resp.read()).extractall('.')
```